# how to pick a point on bitmap created using bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream,

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, bitmap

I am creating a location program. It creates a blueprint of where items are in a warehouse.

```
Dim Storewidth As Integer = 1200
Dim StoreHeight As Integer = 800

Response.Clear()

Dim bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Storewidth, StoreHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
Dim a As Integer = 1 'for a counter to place number down the aisle to show location more clearer
g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias

'background
g.Clear(Color.DarkGray)

'draw rectangle 
g.DrawRectangle(PenColor, X, Y, width, height)

'draw bitmap to the screen
bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg)

g.Dispose()
bmp.Dispose()
Response.End()
```

the above code draws a rectangle. But to speed up getting the coordinates of each rectangle, I would like to click on the bitmap itself. Is there a way to click on the bitmap it just created and return back the X-Y coords.

Addendum: is there a way to overlay something like a grid, on top of the bitmap and click on it perhaps?